# space between items in gridview flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a gridview with 6 items (cards with images and text). I want those 6 items to fit me on the screen but the gridview leaves all the space I can between items by jumping 2 items off the screen.

I leave a picture of what I want and what I have.

Thank you.

```
return MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
  child: Stack(
    alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topCenter,
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        height: 200,
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
      Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 200),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: new DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage("assets/fondo.png"), fit: BoxFit.fill)),
      ),
      Image.asset("assets/cara_simio_banner.png"),
      Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 220),
        child: Text(
          "{CodeJaVu}",
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 25,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 230),
        child: GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          children: items.map((item) {
            return GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {},
              child: CardItem(item),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
)));
```

}

```
Widget CardItem(Item item) {
return Card(
  margin: EdgeInsets.all(40),
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
  ),

    child: 
      Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Image.asset(
            item.image,
            width: 50,
            height: 50,
          ),
          Text(item.name)
        ],
      )
);
}

class Item {
 String _name;
 String _image;

 Item(this._name, this._image);
 String get name => _name;
 set name(String name) => _name = name;

 String get image => _image;
 set image(String image) => _image = image;
}
```

what I have,

[image: what I have]

what I want,

[image: what I want]

Answer (score 44):

add childAspectRatio parametr to GridView.cout counstructor,
and change Card margin.

I've used:

```
..
GridView.count(
              childAspectRatio: 3/2,

..
Card(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 20),
      ..
```

[image]

Answer (score 30):

You can also use mainAxisSpacing and crossAxisSpacing like below.

```
return GridView.builder(
  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
      crossAxisCount: 2, crossAxisSpacing: 8, mainAxisSpacing: 4),
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
  shrinkWrap: true,
  itemCount: widgetList.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return widgetList[index];
  },
);
```

Answer (score 8):

Just add these 2 lines in your GridView widgets:

```
mainAxisSpacing: 20,
crossAxisSpacing: 20,
```

Answer (score 0):

children:

```
space.photos.map((item) {
  return Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
      left: 24,
    ),
    child: ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
      child: Image.network(
        item,
        width: 110,
        height: 88,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    ),
  );
}).toList()
```

Comment: the error is space.photos.map error is map

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).